# How to understand the difference between vertical-align: -0.125em and vertical-align: middle?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I see the code `vertical-align: -0.125em;`, and think about what's the difference between it and `vertical-align:middle`?

Comment: There are the same view among the two code.

Comment: Does MDN documentation help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align If not, explain with more details.

Comment: @ChristopherTaleck 
There are the img element and span element in one span element, and we can set style 'vertical-align:middle' on the img element to let img align with the inner span.

But i see someone use the code 'vertical-align: -0.125em;' to replace of 'vertical-align:middle', so i want to know why.

Comment: I'm sorry, there could be many reasons why they used it for your particular situation. Perhaps the -0.125em measurement just so happens to match the middle alignment.

Comment: Yes, it is relation to line-height. Because different browser has different manifestation. Maybe the numerical value ‘-0.125’ is one appropriate way to let the img align width center.

Comment: More one words, the 'vertical-align: -0.125em;' has different way width 'vertical-align:middle'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align:middle` means

> Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the x-height of the parent

So you need to find the *middle* of your element, the baseline and half the x-height (defined by the `ex` unit).

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(black,black) center/100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0 calc(50% + 0.5ex)/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span></span>
</div>
```

The green line is the basline, the black one on the span element is the middle. We offset the middle by half the x-height (the red line)

`vertical-align: -0.125em` is `vertical-align: <length>` means

> Aligns the baseline of the element to the given length above the baseline of its parent. A negative value is allowed.

Here it's the basline of the element against the baseline of the parent considering an offset:

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(black,black) 0 18px/100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0 calc(18px - 0.125em)/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:-0.125em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span>aq</span>
</div>
```

Note that in some cases the baseline is a bit tricky to find. For an empty element the baseline is the bottom of the element:

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left 0 bottom 0.5em/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:-0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span></span>
</div>
```

It's also the bottom if the element is having `overflow:hidden`

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left 0 bottom 0.5em/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:-0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span></span> <span>aq</span>
</div>
```

It's also the bottom if we deal with an image or SVG

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left 0 bottom 0.5em/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:-0.5em;
}

.box > img {
  vertical-align:-0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span></span> <span>aq</span> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/30/30" >
</div>
```

Note how the image is not aligned the same because `em` will consider the parent `font-size` `50px` unlike the span elements that will consider their own `font-size`. Use `px` and they will align the same:

```css
.box {
  font-size:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) 0 46px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.box > span {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left 0 bottom 10px/100% 1px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  vertical-align:-10px;
}

.box > img {
  vertical-align:-10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text j <span></span> <span>aq</span> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/30/30" >
</div>
```

---

To conclude, there is no explicit relation between `middle` and `-0.125em` since both have different definition and don't use the same references. It may happen that both give the same alignment in some particular cases but it doesn't mean they are equivalent.