# how to set differents baseline for a text part in a table with css

Tags: css

I wish to get something like that:

[image]

I have done many things, like changing Padding or line-height or even margin does nothing

"ROCKY" and "IV" are not on differents base lines...

Is it impossible to do ?

[edit] If it is possible to do a similar thing, without using an HTML table, I am a taker, even if it will force me to change a lot of things on my interface.

```css
table {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      text-align: center;
      background: #FFA500;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      padding: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
    }
    thead {
      font-size: 40px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    thead td {
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    span {
      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-top: 40px
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>
        ROCKY <span>IV</span>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: try `vertical-align: -0.15em;` on the span (related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57832839/8620333)

Comment: ! thank you very much, I admit that my css is very summary

Comment: at the end you wanted to simply center the content, not only adjust the baseline ... in this case, it's a trivial duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif Using the negative vertical alignment is better ... I looked for this answer a few hours. Should I delete my message?

Comment: you are not obliged but you need to be clear in the question to get better answers. vertical centring is different from changing the baselines. The first one is a paricular case of the last and it seems that you simply want to center the text.

Comment: vertical centering has been a problem because different cells in the array are also affected, and the same with colspan="x", that's a mess

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve what you wanted with using `flexbox`.
All you need to do is adding `display: flex;` and `align-items: center` to your `thead td` and remove your `padding-top: 40px;` from `span` tag.

```css
table {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      text-align: center;
      background: #FFA500;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      padding: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
    }
    thead {
      font-size: 40px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    thead td {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    span {
      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td>
        ROCKY <span>IV</span>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

EDIT: if you want to be sure your other `thead td` does not affect by the `display: flex` and other stuff, you can simply add a class to your needed one such as below:

```css
table {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      text-align: center;
      background: #FFA500;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      padding: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ccc;
    }
    thead {
      font-size: 40px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    thead td {
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    span {
      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    thead > tr > td.centering-span > span {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td class="centering-span" colspan="4">
        ROCKY <span>IV</span>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
      <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Finally I will not use this solution, it causes me worry about other cells in my table

Comment: Could you share some illustration of what you exactly are worrying about?

Comment: @MisterJojo I think what you worried about is resolved in the edited answer.

Comment: I have changed your 2th post to show you why it doesn't fit

Comment: @MisterJojo well, this is absolutely right, but `vertical-align: middle;` will work in this situation. So check the second post again to see the results.

Comment: Yes, it's better, but I find that the centered position is too high, and for just one wording, it's easier and more adjustable to use the negative vertical alignment. thank you for your effort (I learned a little thanks to you)!