# Vertically-aligned inline-block element not perfectly centered within container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `vertical-align: middle` to vertically center an `inline-block` element within some text.

```css
p {
  background: red;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
}

span {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span></span>
  &lt;-- Not perfectly aligned
</p>
```

Notice that the element isn't perfectly centered... why is this? Is this a browser off-by-one issue? It repros on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari).

Comment: With 4.5k rep you surely know you're supposed to include code in the question, not just send us to links to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry mate, haven't actually used the SO embedded code snippet before. Added.

Comment: Thanks for the link-- I saw that post and I think it's a different issue. `vertical-align: middle` is "working" in my case, it just isn't pixel-perfect. FWIW, it's better in FF.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57832839/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190413/8620333 ... middle doesn't work like you think

Comment: I don’t believe vertical-align achieves the effect you’re looking for. Would consider flexbox I.e. setting the parent css as: ‘display:flex’ and ‘align-items:center’

Comment: The only other thing to try is removing the white space from your HTML I.e <p><span>Stuff</span></p> all on one line

Comment: I considered flex, but it collapses whitespace, forcing me to add `white-space; pre` or some equivalent. I may be forced to go that route regardless though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: middle;` was never meant to center the element. Here is a more trivial example to better see:

```css
p {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(yellow,yellow) center/100% 1px no-repeat, /* the center */
    red;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size:80px;
  display: block;
}

span {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span></span>
  &lt;-- Not aligned
</p>
```

> Aligns the middle of the element with the baseline plus half the x-height of the parent <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</sup>

Related question for more details:

[How to understand the difference between vertical-align: -0.125em and vertical-align: middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57830401/8620333)

[Vertical align not working on inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35529582/8620333)

[Vertical-align aligns everything else except self](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52634849/8620333)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190413/8620333

Answer (score -2):

Your code has comments and text is not in span.
Try this:

```
<p>
  <span>Not perfectly aligned</span>
</p>


p {
  background: red;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I think downvotes because you didn't understand the question. The text is not meant to be in the span. The span is supposed to be a separate square visual that demonstrates how vertical alignment isn't working properly. Also, the code has no comments in it.

Comment: ok got it, but at first it was not like this, it was comment but after edit it become like it is now, nvm, no issue